# Bolt built in edit content function

Tags: php, symfony, twig, bolt-cms

I'm developing a site with BoltCM and BoltForms.

I've developed a form and an extension that let me insert some content types with only one form.

My problem is on content editing: in my twig template file I read data from my record and I''ve added them to a param array to populate forms, according to the BoltForms doc.

My content type have also one main image field and an image list field. What I'm trying to do is to emulate Bolt built in edit content widgets (the ones in bolt administration panels) and to use them in particularly to delete preassociated content images.

Digging into the code I've found this file [_image.twig](https://github.com/bolt/bolt/blob/6307ce400eb9e74b7f6140bc7a8e684ce38b50c4/app/view/twig/editcontent/fields/_image.twig) but I can't understand how to use it.

Someone can help me?

Comment: This is a rather broad question that will require some back and forth questions. I think https://discuss.bolt.cm/ or use any other more direct way to interact from here: https://bolt.cm/page/community

Comment: ok, i've posted on discuss.bolt.cm, if I'll find a solution I'll post here